What is a good backup mount to secure an action camera to a seatpost?
I've had front lights and cyclometers fly off the handlebar (likely because I didn't hear a clean "click" while attaching them). They survive a fall on the tarmac.
I don't want to bet that an action camera would survive — when it's attached to either the handlebar or the seatpost — and so it would be prudent (thanks, Criggie) to have a backup attachment in case the primary one fails. Also, falling objects could cause mayhem when riding with a group.
A backup attachment could be as simple as getting a camera wrist-strap around the seatpost (and live with the annoyance of pulling the seatpost every time I want to mount the camera).
But maybe there is a better backup solution than a wrist strap. What is a good backup to secure an action camera, at least to the seatpost, but perhaps also to the handlebar?
In case it matters, the camera in question is a GoPro. I'm asking, mind you, for a secondary mounting despite not having yet identified a good primary mounting (the official mounting solution is so bulky it's offensive).

The wrist strap is what Garmin adds to their head units as a back up. It will be hard to find anything better. However, aren't cameras attached with a screw on the GoPro mount, unlike the clicking Garmin interface for the computers and lights?

Without the primary mount decided it will be really hard to say anything on the secondary one. However, the GoPro mount is really popular and also used by third parties not just for cameras, but also for lights, etc.  It will be even harder to use something else, especially when the something else is not originally suported by your device.

I'm aware that a lanyard and a wrist strap are not functionally different, but it's the alternative way that is proposed by many gadgets manufacturers to provide additional securing for their devices (Garmin, Wahoo — although Wahoo also provides a screw to make sure that unit can't be rotated accidentally). The main issue being if the device doesn't have a built-in backup mount, you'll need to find a way to attach one securely. Assuming a GoPro, you'll need an external case to attach a lanyard. But if you don't want to add another failure point, you need to have a case that doesn't have mounting points, but allow to use the camera's mounting points. (the story will probably disappear in the chat, but the mention of Criggie in the question refers to a lost camera because the camera was in a case that didn't close properly, so at some point during the ride, the case opened and the camera felt, in other word, it's a case failure, not a mounting point failure - in that case, a lanyard attached to the case would not have changed the outcome).
Then you can secure the camera using the lanyard. There you have different options, but unmounting the seat post each time is certainly not a requirement, and you can make less unconvenient: adding a carabiner (or a keyring) that you attach directly to the saddle rails, or use the carabiner to close a loop with the lanyard, or inserting the lanyard from the saddle (for example by starting by the nose of the saddle, then the rear, then you the camera to the primary mount - hope it's clear),...
The attention point is that the lanyard remains short enough to avoid that the attached camera reaches the wheel, that could cause much more damage than the loss of a camera.

What I've done with action cameras for kayaking is to tie a length of 2--3mm bungee cord so it fits securely round the camera body.  Exactly how is camera-specific but I may be able to come up with a demo later.  Then I loop another  piece of bungee cord through that, pulling it tight with a cord adjuster (example).  That cord would be left attached to the saddle rails.
On the bike I use a lanyard as a backup for my phone, leaving a strap with a small (keyring type) carabiner attached to the bike.  Arranging it so the carabiner doesn't rattle against the frame is a bit of a pain at least at first.
BTW there are a lot of 3rd party accessories for GoPros and other cameras that copy their mount.  Even if none is perfect, some simple modifications might help (for example replacing the massive thumbscrew with a socket head screw that doesn't stick out)
